# How to remove target folders from IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for scala development, and I find it really annoying that whenever I try and search in the project it returns results from compiled files like things in my `target` folder or compiled twirl templates etc.

Is there a way to remove this from my search index?

Should they even be visible at all in my "Project" pane?

Answer (score 6):

Right-click the directory in the project tool window and select `Mark Directory as -> Excluded`, then the find in path action will not show any results from it.

Then, you can deselect the "Show excluded files" option of the project tool window to completely hide the directory.